# Время жизни временной переменной

Tags: c++

Пусть есть две функции

```
std::string f();
void g(const char*);
```

которые я не могу изменить.
Отличаются ли чем-либо следующие способы их использования:

```
{ g(f().c_str()); } // 1
{ g(f().data()); } // 2
{ std::string tmp = f(); g(tmp.c_str()); } // 3
{ std::string tmp = f(); g(tmp.data());  } // 4
```

Был бы признателен за подробное объяснение работы внутренней кухни в сл-ях 1 и 2. Создается временная переменная типа `std::string`, берется указатель на ее данные, передается в `g()`. Когда уничтожается эта временная переменная?

Спасибо ответившим. Добавлю пару ссылок на EN.stackoverflow, там есть отсылки к стандарту:

[раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214153/lifetime-of-temporaries)

[два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323049/when-do-temporary-parameter-values-go-out-of-scope)

Comment: Когда возникают вопросы про моменты создания/уничтожения, самый простой способ проверить это на практике - пользовательский класс с выводом текста в конструкторах/деструкторе.

Comment: @alexolut это я, конечно, сделал до задания вопроса. К сожалению, это не решает проблему компиляторо-зависимого поведения.

Comment: в данном случае, от компилятора зависеть не должно. А в зависимых случаях, Вы же скорее всего будете проверять на том же компиляторе, где и использовать финальный код. Если конечно не занимаетесь разработкой библиотеки, поставляемой в исходных кодах. В последнем случае, безусловно, надо полагаться на букву Стандарта. Но и здесь возможна ситуация, когда в компиляторе имеется известная ошибка реализации, требующая обходного способа.

Comment: Возможность использовать `data()` вместо `c_str()` наличествует только начиная с С++11. До С++11 не гарантировалось, что `data()` вернет С-строку.

Comment: @AnT, раз уж отписались, правильно ли я понимаю, что в С++11 `data` и `c_str` - полные эквиваленты?

Comment: @andy.37: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Способы отличаются лишь написанием, поведением они не отличаются.
Временные переменные, всегда уничтожаются по [завершении](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4) выполнения [полного выражения](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#10). Релевантные параграфы в C++14: *[intro.execution]p10* и *[class.temporary]p3*

Comment: Спасибо, это уже ближе к тому, что я хотел услышать. Уточнение, в контексте (1) *full-expression* является целиком `g(f().c_str())` или часть `f().c_str()` тоже? Что будет если написать `char *p = f().c_str();`?

Comment: @andy.37, `f().c_str()` является подвыражением первого. Полные выражения, очень грубо, это выражения оканчивающиеся `;`. 1-е и 3-е являются полными выражениями.

Comment: @andy.37 Вот тут - `const char * p = f().c_str(); g(p);` вас действительно ждут неприятности. Потому как строка, возвращенная `f()`, будет уничтожена до вызова `g()`.

Comment: @Harry я так и думал. ОК, всем спасибо, будем считать, что ответ получен))

Answer (score 3):

В последних двух случаях по окончании работы `g()` у вас останется переменная `tmp`, с которой можно продолжать работать. В первых двух случаях доступа к строке, возвращенной `f()`, не будет, она будет уничтожена по окончании работы `g()` автоматически.

В любом случае во время работы функции ее аргументы остаются в области видимости, так что до завершения работы функции уничтожение аргумента не произойдет.

Comment: Это ясно. Для простоты поправил вопрос. Интересует именно поведение `g` - всегда ли оно одинаково

Comment: она будет уничтожена по окончании работы g() автоматически (с). Уточнение - верно ли *по окончании работы g*?

Comment: Тогда по сути - ничем. Разве что теоретически, насколько я помню, когда-то вызов `data()` не гарантировал наличие завершающего нулевого символа. Начиная с C++11 они тождественны.

Comment: @andy.37 Встречный вопрос - а когда? Точка следования, как я понимаю, по завершению работы `g()`, область видимости - тю-тю... Думаете, компилятор отложит уничтожение до выхода из блока? :)

Comment: Скорее боюсь обратного - создается, вычисляется указатель и *уничтожается до вызова g()*, делая указатель невалидным.

Comment: @andy.37 нет, он уничтожается **после** выхода из g(). Увы, у меня нет возможности искать нужный пункт стандарта, но если было бы иначе, мои программы бы не работали.

Comment: @gbg в том то и дело, что у меня тоже все работает в виде 1). Вопрос в том, может ли это зависеть от особенностей компилятора, или это гарантирует стандарт.

Comment: @andy.37 Да конечно гарантирует, иначе бы ни одна сколь-нибудь серьезная программа просто не могла работать. На пункт стандарта, увы, не сошлюсь, я в нем ориентируюсь плохо. Но там явно должно быть что-то об области видимости аргумента функции...